# Hibernate to filter or remove child objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hibernate to filter child object which does not match criteria condtion

I am facing one issue regarding child object remove.

I am applying filter on child object and i want that object only but it is fatching all the object. Please find below
example

In that I have applied filter on Dogs name with Yellow. So I want only yellow object of Dogs. But when I iterating with Parent Object in that case p.getDogs(). It will give all the list of that relation ship. I want list of Dogs object which name would be only 'Yellow'

```
public class TestClass  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Test");
        createDatabaseDate(emf);

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Person> cq = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
        Root<Person> root = cq.from(Person.class);
        cq.select(root);


        Path<String> name = root.join("dogs").get("name");
        cq.where(cb.and(cb.equal(name, "Yellow")));

        TypedQuery<Person> query = em.createQuery(cq);
        for(Person p : query.getResultList()){

             for(Dog dog : p.getDogs()){
                 System.out.println(dog.getName());
             }
        }


        System.out.println(query.getResultList());

        emf.close();
    }
}  



public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String nickName;
    private Integer age;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Dog> dogs;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through all solution but i could not find the solution regarding criteria condition. For the alternative solution I have written jpa query and then i iterate through the object of that result.
        Please find my solution as below.

```
    String hql ="select p.id, p.name,d.name from Person p join fetch p.dogs d where d.name = :name  ";

    Query query = em.createQuery(hql);

    query.setParameter("name", "Yellow");

    List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();
    for (Object[] obj : resultList) {
         System.out.println((Integer)obj[0]);
         System.out.println((String)obj[1]);
         System.out.println((String)obj[2]);
    }
```

By doing this you will only get required child object not all the child object.

Thanks